# Create an expression tree manually

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have the classes

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        this.Map = new MyMap();
    }
    public MyMap Map { get; set; }
}

public class MyMap
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I construct this lambda

```
Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> exp = m => m.Map.MyProperty1;
```

manually using Expression Tree?

Comment: Examine the value of `exp` in the debugger and study the static methods in `Expression` that will allow you to build that tree.

Comment: Can you add something about how you are using exp, this will help me come up with a better example for you.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (MyModel));
var mapProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, "Map");
var myProperty1 = Expression.Property(mapProperty, "MyProperty1");

var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyModel, string>>(myProperty1, parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the PropertyOrField method of Expression, here is a quick example I cooked up using your objects:

```
var model = new MyModel();

var mapExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(model), "Map");
var propExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(mapExpr, "MyProperty1");

Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(propExpr).Compile()(); //Outputs the value of MyProperty1 on the variable called model.
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't there another way of not requiring it to have an instance of the object?

Comment: You will need to experiment to find a way to pass in the instance that works for you, but at some point that instance is required. I will post another example, not related to your use case but hopefully that will give you a better idea of how you could structure this.

Comment: @user3900456 I've decided that my example isn't going to offer as much value as I though it would, I left a comment on the question asking for some more detail, once you post that I will try to come up with an example that fits your use case.